# Node JS Get stops working randomly

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm making a simple get request but after 10 or so requests it stops working. 
It's the same on my local and productions servers. Once it happens all subsequent Get requests fail until node is restarted.

Strange thing is I cannot recreate the issue consistently. It comes and goes.

I know I've given almost no info but I'm not sure what to say. Has anyone had any issue like this?

```
                 var options = {
                        host: 'localhost',
                        port: 80,
                        path: '/first/second/' + data.uid,
                        agent: false

                    }
                    console.log('just before get');
                    http.get(options, function(res) {
                        res.on('data', function() {});
                        io.sockets.emit('load new ' + data.uid, {status: 3});
                        console.log(res.statusCode);

                    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost certainly being affected by the built-in HTTP agent's per-domain connection pool limit. Read up on that in the [node.js http module docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_class_http_agent) and the [hyperquest README/rant](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest). You can adjust it by increasing the agent's `maxSockets` option.

Comment: Well, let's get more precise. Add an 'error' event handler and log the actual errors. We need something better than "stops working". Is the destination web server logging any errors?

Comment: Also show us all the code. The setting name is 'maxSockets' so if you misspell it, it won't have any effect.